# Access hyperledger fabric with CURL

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I have modified the fabcar example to get the data from an external API and store it blocks and it is working fine while running from terminal. Now i have to develop a front end which needs to do a login and have to get the running status for which I am using fabric node-sdk. For the purpose of login and user enrolment, i am using a using a curl function on the basis given [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/balance-transfer) in which they have called the curl with localhost URL link.

I have the blockchain package in AWS, I could not able to trace out the URL and port number which is used to call the user of fabcar. I checked `docker ps -a` and used the port numbers of peers and organization, But it didn't worked. How to get it worked?

Comment: I didn't get the `blockchain package in AWS`? Are you using Amazon Blockchain or you have deployed the same example to AWS? If you have deployed same example to AWS then instead of `localhost:4000` in the `cURL` command, you have to use `IPv4 PublicIP:4000` of AWS instance on which you have deployed Node-SDK. Here `4000` is the port number.

Comment: Yes i deployed in AWS, i tried with `IPv4 PublicIP:4000` but i am receiving Couldn't connect to server error

Comment: Is Port `4000` enabled in `security-groups`?